# What is difference between GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text and GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, headertext

I placed a Placeholder server control on aspx page.

create a Grid-view instance in code behind.

set data-source to it

Now i want to change it header text.so first i tried as given below:

```
GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "ABC";
```

header text not changed.

then i tried with:

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text="ABC";
```

header text changed now.

Added GridView control to PlaceHolder server control:

```
plhGridView.Controls.Add(GridView1);
```

I want to know that why header text not changed when i tried first time?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "ABC";
before binding your datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are not binding columns with your Rows in your former code

```
GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "ABC";
```

You can do this from the former code using RowDataBound handler for details use the following link:

[ASP.NET: When and how to dynamically change Gridview's headerText's in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300963/asp-net-when-and-how-to-dynamically-change-gridviews-headertexts-in-code-behi)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try first time code.
You have to set `GridView1.AllowSorting="true";` and write OnSorting event for GridView.

```
GridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "ABC";
```

If what you want is:

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[4].Text="ABC";
```

This will keep the **sort**.